# Which Analytic philosophers have a positive engagement with Marxism?

Tags: continental-philosophy, analytic-philosophy, marx, marxism

I generally associate Marxist thought to be generally associated with the Continental tradition, however one supposes there are philosophers in the Analytic tradition that have critically evaluated Marxist thought/dogma.

Which are the best known ones, and is there some resource that examines them as a group?

(I have heard of Hayek, but does he count as a philosopher?)

Comment: Are you looking for analytic critics of marxism, then? From your question about positive engagement I thought at first you meant analytic philosophers who employ marxism in their work. One example in this latter category is socialist Logical Positivist Otto Neurath, and perhaps other members of the left wing of the Vienna Circle.

Comment: @ChristopherE: no, your latter impression is correct. Thanks for the ref. I hoping for people more contemporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there is [Analytical Marxism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Marxism)

Of the names mentioned, [G.A. Cohen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._A._Cohen) is probably the most prominent or at least he's the name I've seen the most in my personal experience. His book *Karl Marx's Theory of History: A Defence* is often suggested to people who might otherwise recoil with repugnance towards the Marxist concept of dialectical materialism. I think that'd be a good place to start if you want to see Marx from an Analytic point of view.

Comment: I've held out some vague hope that Marx's ideas could usefully be understood as a meeting place between the continental and analytic traditions. If I'm getting the right impression from that Wikipedia page, "analytic Marxism" is pretty much an effort to reinterpret Marxism without reference to dialectics, so that's not what I was hoping for.